# profile and permission

Tags: profile

All users are able to create an all fields on object A and set/update the `Is Bill-To` and/or `Is Ship-To` flags on that object A.

I gave read and create in object A, and check FLS edit access and read access, But still when I login as user I cannot edit this two fields `Is Bill-To` and/or `Is Ship-To` flags. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is it read only on the page layout?

Comment: No, read only not checked on page layout.

Comment: they are not formula fields?